# What does the Apple .aae file extension stand for?

Tags: apple

What does the Apple .aae file extension stand for? I presume it stands for something, as file extensions usually do.

Arbitrary Apple Extension is my best guess, but [Google](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&ei=pS4PYMTDPKuDhbIPoOOj4AI&q=%22Arbitrary%20Apple%20Extension%22&oq=%22Arbitrary%20Apple%20Extension%22&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyBwgAEEcQsAMyBwgAEEcQsAMyBwgAEEcQsAMyBwgAEEcQsAMyBwgAEEcQsAMyBwgAEEcQsAMyBwgAEEcQsAMyBwgAEEcQsANQAFgAYJUKaAFwAngAgAEAiAEAkgEAmAEAqgEHZ3dzLXdpesgBCMABAQ&sclient=gws-wiz&ved=0ahUKEwiEqrHM-rfuAhWrQUEAHaDxCCwQ4dUDCAw&uact=5) offers no results.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it have nothing to do with photography.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> AA probably stands for Apple Aperture, which was probably the origin
> of the format. Apple Aperture has been discontinued. E may stand for
> Edit, since the file contains image edit history. But no one really
> knows, so it's an Arbitrary Apple Extension.

Comment: Is that a definitive probably? ;)

Answer (score 3):

The file Info dialog in macOS Monterey says `aae` stands for "Apple Adjustments and Edits Sidecar".

Answer (score 2):

[.AAE File Extension](https://fileinfo.com/extension/aae)

> An AAE file contains edits made to an image using the Photos app on an
> iOS device. It is used to transfer non-destructive edits a user has
> made to .JPG images in iOS to the macOS system. AAE files can be found
> accompanying the images for which they contain edits.

[What is File Extension AAE and How Do You Open It](https://www.technipages.com/file-extension-aae)

> An .AAE file is simply the edits that have been made to an existing
> photo on an Apple device. An AAE file can be deleted without erasing
> the actual photo, but you will lose all edits you have made to the
> file. The edit data is saved in an XML format that can be easily
> viewed in a text editor like Notepad.

Comment: OP asks what aae stands for, not what it is.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'm asking what it **stands for**.

Comment: Apple may be the only place to get a satisfactory answer.  What is the reason for knowing what it stands for, does knowing help in any way in using or working .aae files? Will knowing solve a photographic problem that may be better address with another question.

Comment: My *guess* is **A**pple **A**perture **E**xtension.